# Can ARMA and GARCH models be estimated separately in ARMA/GARCH？

Tags: time-series, garch, arima

Can I use the residuals of the ARMA model to build a GARCH model(with Zero mean)?
If so, does this mean that this GARCH model(with Zero mean) has no effect on ARMA's estimates. For example, if I want to use ARMA models to predict returns, then GARCH (with Zero mean) will not help, unless both models estimate at the same time. Thanks.

Comment: This has been discussed multiple times at Cross Validated. Some relevant threads are [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=arma+garch+simultaneously+estimation), especially [this one](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/87600/arma-garch-estimation-in-sequence/128745#128745).

Answer (score 1):

You can combine AR(I)MA and GARCH models. For instance, a (Gaussian) ARMA(1,1)-GARCH(1,1) model would read as
\begin{align*}
r_t &= c + ar_{t-1} + b\epsilon_{t-1} + \epsilon_t, \\
\sigma^2_t &= \omega + \alpha \sigma_{t-1}^2 + \beta \epsilon_{t-1}^2
\end{align*}
where $\epsilon_t\mid\mathcal{F}_{t-1}\sim N(0,\sigma_t^2)$.

You should first test for stationary returns and heteroscedastic variance.Using information criteria like AIC, BIC and HQIC you can first find the optimal ARMA parameters and then continue with fitting the GARCH model. A likelihood ratio test may be useful as well. You can improve the fit by using a Student's $t$-distribution or a GED distribution or by using T-GARCH or EGARCH models to allow for asymmetry. Don't forget diagnostics like checkinng the final residuals (homoscedastic, QQ-plot etc.)

Comment: I'm not familiar with fitting arima-garch but wouldn't the two equations have to be estimated simultaneously since $\epsilon_{t-1}$ and $\sigma^2_t$ are related ? Thanks.

Comment: They can be fitted simultaneously. But the number of possible models quickly increases. To simplify, you can do it in two steps, as well. The latter results as trade-off between accuracy and computation time

Comment: The difference lies in how the maximum likelihood estimator will penalize different observations. In particular, a GARCH model can allow for temporarily large deviations from the mean to not be a big deal by letting the associated conditional variance be large.

Comment: Thanks. But just to make sure I understand:  you estimate the $r_{t}$ equation first to get the c, a, b and estimates $\hat\sigma^2$ and $\hat\epsilon_t$. Then you use those estimates in the second equation in order to estimate only $\alpha$ and $\beta$ ? Is that right.

Comment: Oh, the reason I ask is because doing it that way seems inefficient in that information is not being used that's there. But I would imagine that simultaneous estimation is way more complicated.  Also, I meant to say that I don't understand what you mean by "the number of possible models quickly increases". It's still just one model ? Thanks.

Comment: @markleeds I should've been more precise: I first find the optimal amount of lags in the ARMA process. Using those numbers, I find the best lags for the GARCH model. Then, I jointly estimate the entire model. Say, I allow for 2 lags everywhere. My procedure first compares ARMA(1,1), ARMA(2,1), ARMA(1,2) and ARMA(2,2) and finds (say) ARMA(2,1) to be best. Then, I estimate ARMA(2,1)-GARCH(1,1), ARMA(2,1)-GARCH(2,1), ARMA(2,1)-GARCH(1,2) and ARMA(2,1)-GARCH(2,2) and find the best model here. Decision is based on information criterion + likelihood ratio tests.Otherwise, I'd need to test 4^4 models

Comment: Thanks Alex. I get it now. But one last question. How do you do the joint estimation part ? Do you figure out the likelihood and maximize it or use say an R package ? No more bothers. I promise. I see these joint equations in the macro-econometrics literature quite a bit but I haven't attempted to estimate one which is why I'm asking. Thanks.

Comment: Don't worry Mark! I happen to use Matlab, not R. In Matlab, there is a function called ``estimate'' which estimates an ARIMA model (which can be linked with a GARCH model). So really, it's two lines in Matlab, but I guess there's something similar in R? I don't know for certain though.  If I may, what macro-economic variables are modelled using an ARIMA-GARCH models? I only used it for stock returns thus far.

Comment: @Alex: Thanks. I know that R has rugarch but I don't know if it does simultaneous estimation with other equations. As far as your question, I was talking about the more generic case and not necessarily arma-garch. The rational expectations literature has tons of examples where there are systems of equations. R has systemfit package but I was just wondering how you did it. Thanks.

Comment: Alex, see also my comment to the OP.

Comment: @RichardHardy I agree with consistency. I guess the question is the trade-off between computional effort and rigour. In an ideal world, I fully agree with the joint estimation. The two step approach is much faster though.